# Problem using useForm from "react-hook-form"

Tags: reactjs, typescript

I'm creating a simple form in react using react-hook-form with typescript and I'm having some trouble when I add the following line on my app code:

```
const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();
```

When I add this simple line the content I rendered disappear, receiving a white HTML page:

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

index.tsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);


reportWebVitals();
```

App.tsx code:

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';

export default function App() {
    const {
        register,
        handleSubmit,
        formState: { errors },
    } = useForm();
    const onSubmit = (data:any) => console.log(data);

    return (
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
            <input {...register('firstName')} />
            <input {...register('lastName', { required: true })} />
            {errors.lastName && <p>Last name is required.</p>}
            <input {...register('age', { pattern: /\d+/ })} />
            {errors.age && <p>Please enter number for age.</p>}
            <input type="submit" />
        </form>
    );
}
```

Any idea of what is going on?

Comment: Is there an error in the browser console?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.